# Flip a fair coin repeatedly. Will there be infinitely many moments when the ratio "heads:total flips" is very large?

Tags: probability

> We repeatedly flip a fair coin, and let $R_n$ be the ratio of Heads to
>   the total number of flips after $n$ flips. For any $x\in(0,1)$, there
>   are almost surely infinitely many $n$ for which $R_n$  exceeds $x$.

Is this statement true? If so, how do we prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not true. This follows from the strong [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers). (The weak law is not sufficient to answer the question.)

Answer (score 2):

No. By Strong Law $R_n \to \frac 1 2$ with probability $1$. So there is probability $1$ that $R_n <\frac 3 4$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.